# Bind data from a key,value structure list with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this list with a key,value structure that stores the data coming from a JSON structure and I want to print this data in a table with an ng-repeat.

```
var data = [
          {
            id: 1,
            name : "Peter",
            lastname : "Smith",
            age : 36
          }, {
            id: 2,
            name : "Peter",
            lastname : "Smith",
            age : 36
          }
        ];

        $scope.itemDictionary = {};
        angular.forEach(data, function(item){
            var obj = {};
            var valObj = {};

            valObj.name = item.name;
            valObj.lastname = item.lastname;
            valObj.age = item.age;

            obj[item.id] = valObj;
            if(!$scope.itemDictionary[item.id]){
                 $scope.itemDictionary[item.id] = obj;
            }
        });
```

I know that it should be **ng-repeat="d in something"** inside a table but I dont know how to achive this based on the structure that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-repeat="(key,value) in itemDictionary"`

```
<div ng-app="exampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

        {{itemDictionary}}

        <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in itemDictionary track by key">
            <h1>ID: {{key}}</h1>
            <h1>Name: {{value[$index + 1].name}}</h1>
            <h1>Lastname: {{value[$index + 1].lastname}}</h1>
            <h1>Age: {{value[$index + 1].age}}</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

example: http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/vGoqzr

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Comment: @kennechu U're welcome. If this answer helped to solve your problem, marks as correct answer for future visits to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but why are you using so much unnecessary hashes.
you can just simply assign your json data to any scope variable and then use it in view.
Example -:

```
//inside controller...
 var data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name : "Peter",
        lastname : "Smith",
        age : 36
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name : "Peter",
        lastname : "Smith",
        age : 36
      }
    ];

   $scope.itemDictionary = data;


 //inside view...

<table>
 <tr id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in itemDictionary">
   <td>{{item.id}}</td>   
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   <td>{{item.lastname}}</td>
   <td>{{item.age}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

that's it... :)